# What controls the precision when writing reals in postgres copy command?

Tags: postgresql, copy

I do the following copy command from psql:

```
copy yy_caa_epdall to '/tmp/CAAImport-1234567' delimiter '|' csv header;
```

and get a file with lines like the following:

```
1011192|1|1.2|0.34|44.8|0.3|57.4|0.31|19.3|41.7|0.23|7.9|0.2|4.9|0.19||||||||||-0.031|0.22|0.02|0.12|0.27|0.14|5.278|0.17|8.605|0.064|||-0.24||-0.11|0.16|1.8|0.26||
```

When I issue the same command through jdbc within a scala program the same row looks like this:

```
1011192|1|-1.20000005|0.340000004|44.7999992|0.300000012|57.4000015|0.310000002|19.2999992|41.6999969|0.230000004|7.9000001|0.200000003|4.9000001|0.189999998||||||||||-0.0309999995|0.219999999|0.0199999996|0.119999997|0.270000011|0.140000001|5.27799988|0.170000002|8.60499954|0.064000003|||-0.239999995||-0.109999999|0.159999996|1.79999995|0.25999999||
```

This is under Mac 10.10.2.  I would normally suspect an environment variable but nothing was immediately obvious.

All numerical fields are type real.  psql version is 9.3.5

Comment: What seems to be wrong? Floating point numbers are approximations by definition.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the end of the world, I just want it the same so it's easier to compare with old files.  But _something_ is different.

Comment: To quote [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL), "_If you require exact storage and calculations (such as for monetary amounts), use the numeric type instead_".

Comment: Might also want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The point is not about floating point representation of numbers.  The point that it is that 2 apparently identical commands (cut and paste in fact) behave differently. Why?

Comment: Was it literally `copy` in psql, or `\copy`?